# Copy rows from multiple excel sheets to a summary page based on several criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance for reading this, and for any help at all that you may give. I don't know any VBA but I tracked down some codes from these forums.

I'm trying to copy all rows from three source sheets (Ortigas, Franchise, and Movu) to the Summary tab if they match two criteria:

(1) - date = date today as shown in column A, 
(2) - recipient as shown on column D matches what's on the drop down in 'Summary!'B3.

*[Screenshot of sample data from the source sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fMor.png)*

> [image]

*[Summary page with drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce7EC.png)*

> [image]

Attached is my workbook.[workbook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1FbsjQ6RkncVFNlMy1aWkdQNnc)

This is the code I have so far but it says syntax error because of the following line:

```
Set ws1 = Sheets(Array("Ortigas", "Franchise", "Movu")) Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary"): ws1.Select
```

I think it's because I put in an array of sheets instead of just one sheet. I've tried different iterations to fix it but it doesn't work. How do I make ws1 refer to an array of sheets?

Hoping for a kind soul who can help me! Thank you so much.

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim sheetsArray As SheetsA
    Set sheetsArray = Sheets(Array("Ortigas", "Franchise", "Movu"))

    Dim target As Range
    Dim sheetObject As Worksheet

    ' change value of range 'a1' on each sheet from sheetsArray
    For Each sheetObject In sheetsArray
        Set target = sheetObject.Range("A1")
        target.Value = "Test"
    Next sheetObject
End Sub

Sub FindNext_Copy_Data()
    Dim Last_Row As Long, Next_Row As Long, First_Find As Long
    Dim Range_Value As Range, a As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim Today_Date As Date, ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Today_Date = Date
    Set ws1 = Sheets(Array("Ortigas", "Franchise", "Movu")) Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary"): ws1.Select
    Next_Row = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Last_Row = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Range_Value = Range(Cells(1, "A"), Cells(Last_Row, "A"))

    With Range_Value
        Set a = .Find(What:=Today_Date, LookAt:=xlPart)
        First_Find = a.Row
        Do
            a.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ws2.Cells(Next_Row, 1): Next_Row = Next_Row + 1
            Set a = .FindNext(a)
        Loop While (a.Row <> First_Find)
    End With

    ws2.Select: Set ws1 = Nothing: Set ws2 = Nothing: Set Range_Value = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: To clarify, the summary page should show all rows from the source sheets that are dated 5/17/2017, with recipient = "Ortigas ATM"

Comment: And how are you planing to run the code? Worksheet.SelectionChange? can you also share your spreadsheet?

Comment: How "clearly" is something wrong? Do you expect us to build your environment to run your code so we can see what is wrong or are you prepared to share what you think is wrong and how that manifests?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've attached the worksheet and edited my post with info re: the syntax error I get. It says there's an error on the following line: Set ws1 = Sheets(Array("Ortigas", "Franchise", "Movu")) Set ws2 = Sheets("Summary"): ws1.Select

Comment: I added a form button so I can use it to run the macro with every change in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

The following line won't compile with the Array argument:

```
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Ortigas", "Franchise", "Movu"))
```

You'll have to choose one of the worksheets for it to work (say "Ortigas"); ie:

```
Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ortigas")
```

Your first .Find command should have the additional parameter:

```
Set a = .Find(What:=Today_Date, LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

To ensure the copy happens when the 2nd condition is true, you can nest the copy command in an if statement:

```
If ws1.Cells(a.row,"D").Value=ws2.Cells(3,"B").Value Then
   a.EntireRow....
Endif
```

Also you don't need to set ws1 and ws2 to Nothing.  Once the subroutine returns these variables go out of scope anyway, so you can delete those statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Will work on your suggestions. However, It's essential for me to pull data from all the source sheets and not just one sheet. Is there a way to have the code compile data from an array of sheets?

Comment: You'll need another loop to do each sheet one at a time.